# How to test the login in Cypress with Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL)

Tags: reactjs, authentication, testing, cypress, azure-ad-msal

Trying to test React application using Cypress, Getting the issues while logging in.

The application we are using MASL third party login for Authentication.

Getting the following issues:
 --> Couldn't control Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) login popup window using Cypress.
 --> #access_token popup is not closing in Cypress automatically (in actual application closing automatically).
 --> To make all remaining test cases to wait until login popup is closed and redirected back to the application.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you will find your happiness [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71560913/cypress-microsoft-authentication-dont-work-properly)!

For my part, I use a solution already proposed on the net but I have a problem with the first execution of the "cy.request" command to the Microsoft authority.

I invite you to test my solution and to give me feedback on the possible difficulties encountered.